# Halmos's Proof of Schroeder Bernstein: WLOG, taking $X \cap Y = \emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

In the first paragraph of Halmos's proof of the Schroeder-Bernstein theorem, he comments that we can assume the sets $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint without loss of generality.

I've seen some constructions, but I'm trying to fully understand why the resulting sets are disjoint. First, some bookkeeping. So we have sets $X$ and $Y$ for which there are injections $X \hookrightarrow Y$ and $Y \hookrightarrow X$. Both can be assumed nonempty, which I think Halmos is assuming at the start of the proof.  If $X = Y = \emptyset$, they're vacuously in bijection, and if only one of $X,Y$ is empty, I can't write functions in both directions since I can't map from a nonempty set to an empty set. If both are finite, the result is rather trivial, so I think we start from the premise that both $X$ and $Y$ are infinite, which is a more interesting result.

The construction then is some variation of the below. Replace each $x \in X$ with $(x,1)$ and each $y$ with $(y,0)$. Then $1 \neq 0$, so every element of the resulting sets $X'$ and $Y'$ are distinct, so $X' \cap Y' = \emptyset$. Furthermore, $X \cong X'$ and $Y \cong Y'$ via the maps $x \mapsto (x,1)$ and $y \mapsto (y,1)$, so if I establish $X' \cong Y'$, then by composing maps, I get $X \cong Y$.

Assuming everything I've written thus far is fine, my problem is what exactly are the $0$ and $1$ in this case because I don't know what the universe is I'm allowed to draw from. I always have to worry about the possibility that $X \subset Y$ or $Y \subset X$, in which case it might not make sense to pick $x \in x$ and $y \in Y$ for this construction. Under the assumption that the sets are infinite, can I just say pick $\eta \in X$, $\gamma \in Y$, with $\eta \neq \gamma$, and replace $x \in X$ with $(x,\eta)$ and $y \in Y$ with $(y, \gamma)$, calling the new sets $X'$ and $Y'$, respectively, and because $\eta \neq \gamma$, $x' \neq y'$ for every $x' \in X'$ and $y' \in Y'$?

Comment: By the time you get to the section on Schroeder-Bernstein (Section 22), Halmos has already defined the meaning of $0$ and $1$: on Section 11, he defines $0=\varnothing$, and $1=0^+=0\cup\{0\} = \varnothing\cup\{\varnothing\}=\{\varnothing\}$. So not sure why you have qualms about "$0$" and "$1$". You let $X'=X\times\{0\}$, and $Y'=Y\times\{1\}$. You do not need to assume they are nonempty (or infinite): if either of them is empty, the rest of the definitions just lead you to empty sets. It is certainly true that you can decompose the empty set into a union of three "disjoint" empty sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you only need to ensure that $\eta \neq \gamma$. This can be done as you described, but you can also just take $\eta = \varnothing$ and $\gamma = \{\varnothing\}$. In fact, under the usual (von Neumann) set-theoretic construction of natural numbers, $0$ is precisely $\varnothing$ and $1$ is $\{\varnothing\}$, and your original construction is perfectly sensible with these definitions.